# How to use SQL from asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql

Building a relatively simple website, and need to store some data in the database (mainly authentication, but there's some per-user stuff). I've worked on a couple of websites previously, and used database there too, but never liked the way I accessed the database.

The way I usually did this was by having a SqlMethods.cs, which basically was a static class with a whole lot of static methods such as `bool CheckUserExistence(string username, string password)` and `SqlDataReader GetJobListings(int advertiserId)`, each of which was essentially "open connection, call a sproc, return what it returns". This approach seems un-natural to me, however. I cant quite put my mind to what I want it to look like, but this seems...weird.

So, my question is this: how do you  access the database from your asp.net projects?
I am using SQL2005. I also dont think I'll need an ORM of any kind, since there really isnt that much to get from the DB, but maybe its easier with one? Suggest something.
Thanks!

*Edit*:I currently decided to just create a static class `Sql` that will have a number of sql-related methods (such as `ExecuteReader(sprocName, params[])`, etc) that will call the sproc with the given parameters and just return the DataReader.
Then, have classes for specific functionality, such as `Authentication` with methods like `CheckUserExistence(username, password)` and `LogoffUser(session)`. These methods would just call `Sql.ExecuteReader("sp_Auth_CheckUserExistence", _some_params_here_)` and process the result as needed.
I don't know if thats good or bad, but it seems to work for me at the moment. Plus, I like the way it feels - its all nicely separated functionality-wise.

So, any more suggestions?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and/or the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: .Net 3.5 , VS2008 (well, VS2010B2 at the moment, but once that dies,I'll go back to 2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx

Comment: LINQ to SQL allows you to drag and drop your database onto a DataContext file.  This automatically maps all tables, views and stored procedures.  You call call your SPs through the auto generated functions and they can return the appropriate, strongly typed data

Comment: Hmm, I should've seen this one coming. Linq is great for what its made for, but its not what I need. I need something like SomeClass.CheckIfUserExists(username, password); etc.   

See edit of the question to see how I currently decided to do it.

Comment: Well theres nothing thats going to have anything like CheckIfUserExists unless you are using a out of the box database configuration.  Linq would be good for building that method instead, then you could call a method like CheckIfUserExists which will handle the Linq part for you.

Comment: Allright, this seems like a better suggestion in general, though (at least for now) I'm going to do it with just calls to `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(...)`. Im going to accept this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to create a data access class for each table in your database.  It should have private variables and public properties for all of the columns in the table and the methods you describe should fill the internal variables (or use them to update the database).

```
Public Class MyTable
    Private _id As Integer
    Private _Name as String

    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Integer
       ' Regular stuff here
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String
        ' Regular stuff here
    End Property

    Public Sub Load()
        ' Call SQL and get a data reader.
        ' Set _id and _Name from the data reader.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, in your other code:

```
Dim mt As New MyTable
mt.Load()
' Now use mt.ID and mt.Name to access the data
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I want. This loads the data from a DB table into a class. Not what I needed (though I guess its impossible to say what I actually want from my description. heh.)

Comment: Each class can also have static methods that directly call the database, which is pretty much what you've described in your edit.